# How to post to SharePoint2013 Social Feed with ImageData

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

I want to post message with image to SharePoint 2013 Social Feed.

On Browser, I can post message with image. But from API (CSOM), I can't. I looked for the API, but I couldn't find any.

How can I post messages that contain an image to a social feed using CSOM?

Answer (score 1):

You have to play with the SocialAttachment class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.social.socialattachment_members.aspx

Then you can defined the type of the attachment (image, video or document) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.social.socialattachmentkind.aspx

```
SocialPostCreationData postCreationData = new SocialPostCreationData();
postCreationData.ContentText = "My feed content";

SocialAttachment attachment = new SocialAttachment();
attachment.AttachmentKind = SocialAttachmentKind.Image;
attachment.Uri = "Url_To_Image";
postCreationData.Attachment = attachment;
```

Now, the tricky part will consist of uploading the image in current feed on the personal site.